# JasperInitializer in tomcat 8 embedded mode

Tags: java, tomcat, nullpointerexception, tomcat8

I'm in the process of migrating embedded tomcat application from 7.0.59 to tomcat 8.0.20
After updating the Tomcat version when I'm starting the embedded server and try to access the home page I'm getting a `NullPOinterException`

```
ERROR {org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher} -  Servlet.service() for servlet bridgeservlet threw exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldResourcePath(JspCompilationContext.java:536)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:469)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1430)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.doParse(ParserController.java:227)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.ParserController.parse(ParserController.java:100)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.generateJava(Compiler.java:199)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:336)
    at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Compiler.compile(Compiler.java:323)
    at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:570)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:356)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:396)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:340)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:155)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:80)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:721)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:466)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:391)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:318)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(RequestDispatcherAdaptor.java:30)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor$RequestDispatcherAdaptor.forward(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:362)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.forward(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:198)
    at org.apache.tiles.servlet.context.ServletTilesRequestContext.dispatch(ServletTilesRequestContext.java:185)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:419)
    at org.apache.tiles.impl.BasicTilesContainer.render(BasicTilesContainer.java:370)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.action.ActionHelper.render(ActionHelper.java:52)
    at org.wso2.carbon.ui.TilesJspServlet.service(TilesJspServlet.java:101)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.helper.ContextPathServletAdaptor.service(ContextPathServletAdaptor.java:37)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ServletRegistration.service(ServletRegistration.java:61)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.processAlias(ProxyServlet.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.http.servlet.internal.ProxyServlet.service(ProxyServlet.java:68)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.servlet.DelegationServlet.service(DelegationServlet.java:68)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:291)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.filter.CharacterSetFilter.doFilter(CharacterSetFilter.java:61)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:79)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:49)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1086)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:659)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:223)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1558)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1515)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I debug the tomcat8 source and found that `tldCache` inside the `EmbeddedServletOption` is null. This is been set by the `onStartup` method in the `JasperInitializer`

What can I do to make sure that it get invoke
or how can I manually invoke `org.apache.jasper.servlet.JasperInitializer.onStartup` 
during web app startup?

I'm embedding tomcat 8 inside the application.

Comment: Has this issue been solved? If so, how?

Comment: I manually called the JasperInitilizerSCI from the code. That will solve the issue. But I dont think it is the best approach

Comment: No problem, I solved it, but the solution did make my server slow on startup, but since this is the first successful start it could be anything that caused it.

Comment: If it helps any, I found my solution by looking at the spring boot code @ http://apiwave.com/java/snippet/spring-projects/spring-boot/30b181573e1564f56644428da284e9e523a8fd9f/spring-boot.src.main.java.org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.JasperInitializerLifecycleListener.java and then realized that wiring it that way didn't make sense. I reviewed the source code and looked at my existing lifecyclelistener, the default ContextConfig lifecyclelistener and that code calls addServletContainerInitializer()

Comment: Anyhow, thanks for posting what you had found. You finding the JasperInitializer saved me a lot of time in solving this issue. It corrected both my tag library issues and my expression language issues.

Comment: glad that helps u :) Since you had put that as answer I will mark it as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to this issue is somewhat hidden and doesn't seem to be documented but it can sometimes be solved with one line of code.

```
context.addServletContainerInitializer(new JasperInitializer(), null);
```

I admit the server is slow to start once this is added, but it is now functional.