# Openfire error : Unable to compile jsp

Tags: java, jsp, compilation, openfire

i am compiling openfire from source and it compiles properly . But it cause problems while accessing web plugin .
Error :

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: Unable to compile class for JSP
at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.compile(JspCompilationContext.java:579)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:357)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:405)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:349)
at org.eclipse.jetty.jsp.JettyJspServlet.service(JettyJspServlet.java:107)
```

Caused By

```
java.lang.NullPointerException at org.apache.jasper.JspCompilationContext.getTldResourcePath(JspCompilationContext.java:530)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseTaglibDirective(Parser.java:410)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseDirective(Parser.java:469)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parseElements(Parser.java:1428)
at org.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.parse(Parser.java:139)
```

Help me i think its due to api problem ... please help me

Comment: The exception similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29097407/jasperinitializer-in-tomcat-8-embedded-mode. If you are running embedded tomcat application, check the answer of that question.

Comment: Thanks but now i got it , i compiled the latest source from github and then change the classpath file to "https://github.com/Connectify/Openfire/blob/master/build/eclipse/classpath"  .